# Client Application Authentication with JAX-WS

Tags: java, authentication, jpa, jax-ws

Hi all I am reading a tutorial on [Application Authentication with JAX-WS](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/), and in short it boils down to:

```
@Override
public String getHelloWorldAsString() {

MessageContext mctx = wsctx.getMessageContext();

//get detail from request headers
    Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
    List userList = (List) http_headers.get("Username");
    List passList = (List) http_headers.get("Password");

    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    if(userList!=null){
        //get username
        username = userList.get(0).toString();
    }

    if(passList!=null){
        //get password
        password = passList.get(0).toString();
    }

    //Should validate username and password with database
    if (username.equals("mkyong") && password.equals("password")){
        return "Hello World JAX-WS - Valid User!";
    }else{
        return "Unknown User!";
    }

}
```

As you can see the method checks for authentication and returns a result depending, but this would mean all my web services methods will need to check for authentication.

So basically I want to know how to make it that authorization only occurs once? (when client logs in).

I had a few simple ideas:

1) Making the web service only allow a single `login()` method which will return `null` in case of a wrong login or an object instance of another class which has all other methods (i.e that make up the functionality of the web service), thus unless authentication is passed client wont have access to web service methods.

2) Another method I see is perhaps one-way client SSL? ([Configuring Transport-Level Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13713/transport.htm#autoId2))

Is this how it should be done or am I missing something?

For a bit more background I have a web service (jax-ws) which has methods to query db etc using JPA as the databasemanager/persistor. My client will interface with a Swing UI and connect to the web service.

Comment: Is your web service deployed in it's own web application, or do you have both this web service and a user interface in a single app?

Comment: @Syon No web service is on a server (okay for test purposes its localhost) and the client will be connecting from other pcs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some type of authentication needs to occur for every web service call, be it via username and password, certificate, or some type of token (that was issued earlier by calling a "login" operation).

If all you're really looking to do is get the authentication code out of your web service, the easiest (and safer) solution is generally to let the J2EE container handle authentication and authorization via SSL/TLS and Basic Authentication (and your client sends the username and password with every call as in your option #2).

To get started on configuring this security [see this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html)

Specific things to look at in it are `<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>`, `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` and `<web-resource-collection>` configuration.

Comment: +1 thanks I am starting to understand now... And I guess it makes sense authentication should occur every call... As for the `<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>` etc would that be added to the XML which ANT/wsimport builds the service from? And on that I named mine wsbuild, however I see web.xml used alot,.. is that the standard naming convention for the xml which ant builds to form the web service?

Comment: And 1 last thing... Is the SSL authentication method a good way to go? How would I safely store password for SSL on the client app which cant be decompiled and the username and password captured by another person who will than create their own malicious client? because in the link I gave for my 2nd idea it has: `private final static String USERNAME = ....;
  private final static String PASSWORD = ....;` which IMO is very easy to see the fields (by see i mean decompile etc), with minor know how

Comment: web.xml is where everything from the tutorial I mentioned goes. ANT and wsimport will not add anything to it automatically, you need to configure it to secure the URL within your web application that the web service is hosted at yourself. As for SSL, yes you should be using SSL/TLS any time you're passing credentials over the wire. Securely storing the username and password in an app running on the clients machine though is a whole other problem (and a very hard one). Once someone has your code, virtually anything you've done can be undone.

Comment: The proper way to do authentication without storing credentials in your app would be to give each user their own set of credentials, prompt the user for them when your app starts up, and then use those credentials in the web service call. Of course you're then left with having to manage a whole bunch of user credentials.

Comment: *The proper way to do authentication without storing credentials in your app would be to give each user their own set of credentials, prompt the user for them when your app starts up* argh of course where has my logic gone ?!?! Thanks alot for your answer and comments I have a much better view on what is happening and how it should be happening :)